# Duplicate entry - playservice and applozic

Tags: android, google-play-services, applozic

Without Applozic gradle dependecy all workk well.

In Project level build.gradle I have:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

In App leves my build.gradle is:

```
dependencies {

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
   compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:4.3'
}
```

Gradle sync correctly. When I run log produce

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/iid/zzb$zza$zza.class

If I remove applozic line all work.

I found similar question, but not like mine

Answer (score 2):

Applozic android chat sdk v4.3 was using Google play services 8.4.0 because of that it was giving duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/iid/zzb$zza$zza.class error. We have upgraded to latest version of Google play service 9.0.2.

Here is the new version

```
compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:4.4'
```

and here is the applozic android chat sdk [documentation link](https://www.applozic.com/docs/android-chat-sdk.html)